# ActiveRecord - check if value is null, 0 or 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
Rails 3.2.2, Ruby 1.9.2
```

I'm using MySql and there is column "MyColumn" of TINYINT type. I need to show the status of it on a page. So I created a helper method.

```
module MyControllerHelper
 def result(a)
    case a
      when false then 'false 0'
      when true then 'true 1'
      when blank? then 'blank or nil'
    end     
  end
end
```

The bottom line is that it can also be empty or nil. So it doesn't work as I need. It constantly returns either `false 0` or `true 1` but never `blank or nil` even if it should do.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `case` uses `===` for comparison so that's equivalent to:

```
if false === a
  'false 0'
elsif true === a
  'true 1'
elsif blank? === a
  'blank or nil'
else
  nil
end
```

Rails adds a `blank?` method to Object that [looks like this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2a371368c91789a4d689d6a84eb20b238c37678a/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L14):

```
def blank?
  respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
end
```

so you can call `blank?` anywhere, even without a specified receiver: there will always be a `self` and it will always be an Object. Now you should see that `when blank?`, while syntactically valid, makes no sense at all: it doesn't call `a.blank?` and see if a true value came back, it simply checks `self.blank? === a` for whatever `self` happens to be.

You're probably better off using an explicit `if/else` for this:

```
def result(a)
  # false.blank? is true so you don't want a.blank? here.
  if(a.nil?)
    'nil'
  elsif(a)
    'true 1'
  else
    'false 0'
  end
end
```